# How to make a "Summary Slide" in Impress, listing the titles of all slides automatically

Tags: libreoffice, table-of-contents, libreoffice-impress

In LibreOffice Impress 5.0.5.2 I opened a .ppt presentation where each slide has a title and a body (visible in screenshot).

I would like to create a "**table of content**" slide that would just list all slide titles.

"Insert > [Summary Slide](https://help.libreoffice.org/Impress/Summary_Slide)" sounds exactly like the kind of feature I need, but unfortunately it is greyed out:

[image: LibreOffice Summary Slide]

**QUESTION:** How to easily make such a summary slide, without having to copy-paste each title?

Comment: The summary slide entry is greyed out as long as no slide is selected. So after selecting a slide as first summary entry, it should work.

Comment: @tohuwawohu: I had tried that but it does not work. I just tried again, selecting a slide in the slides view, the menu is still greyed out.

Comment: Oh - i've just seen that you're editing a ppt file - i've tested it with a native odp file. Did you try to save the ppt as odp, or copy the content to a fresh odp file? I will check tomorrow if i can reproduce the issue with a ppt file.

Comment: In LibreOffice-5.1 I found that at "Slide > Summary Slide" (with a *.pptx, LO-5.1.6.2/Ubuntu-16.04/Linux).

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to select the first slide in your presentation **with a title field**. In the slides without a title field, the Summary slide option will be greyed out.

Go to the first slide **with a title field**:

> Slide -> "Summary Slide"

BTW, Insert -> Field -> Slide title does not seem to count as a title field (?).